# running tlb from bin -- interop.scripting.dll not found

Tags: arcobjects, installation, arcgis-9.3, visual-studio, library

I rebuilt a custom command in VS Express 2013, added from file to a custom toolbar in ArcMap 9.3.1. The form appears, but upon running I immediately get an error about a missing Interop.Scripting.dll file. I wonder if this is due to the fact that the reference to this dll points to the obj\Debug folder and not bin\Debug, where the tlb (type library) file resides. This is what VS automatically points to, however, and I don't think I'm supposed to change those references. I had the impression I could use custom commands without deploying an executable msi?

To be clear, I am building this from source - there should be no need to use regasm or the sort to register the COM files.

Here's a glance at some of my references. I think this is where the problem lies.

[image: Pic]
[image: Pic]

Answer (score 1):

This has been solved. Not entirely sure of the details, but I started fresh with a backup copy of the source and left the original .NET and COM references as-is. The key difference is the use of powerpacks.VS as opposed to the new 3.0, and older ESRI dlls (dating to 9.1 period). All had copy-local set to true, thereby copying all relevant dlls and coms to the bin folder. For some reason this build works fine... trying to modernize the references somehow messed things up, possibly due to a compatibility issue, or some other oversight.